# Is it safe to delete airflow.db file?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver, airflow-api

I can't login in the web UI of airflow. I always get this `Invalid login error`.

When I run the  `airflow users list` the users are there.
So my option is to delete the `airflow.db` and run `airflow db init` again.
I want to know if it is safe to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is with users then you can simply use create/delete user CLI:

[create](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#create_repeat1):

```
airflow users create [-h] -e EMAIL -f FIRSTNAME -l LASTNAME [-p PASSWORD] -r
                     ROLE [--use-random-password] -u USERNAME
```

[delete](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#delete_repeat3):

```
airflow users delete [-h] [-e EMAIL] [-u USERNAME]
```

There is no need to run `db init` for the problem you described.

Comment: I have already do this and create an Admin user. Then I create another User from the airflow UI. When I logged out from the Admin user to login to the User I created I got the invalid login error and I can't get logged in to the Admin user.